# Java cannot find symbol for any Arrays?

Tags: java, compiler-construction, compiler-errors

So, It's so annoying.

I made 2 programs.

Number #1 :

```
class Arrays2 {
public static void main(String[] args){

    String sentenceBest[] = {"This is the first sentence!"};

    char chR[] = sentenceBest.toCharArray();        

    for (int counter = 0; counter < chR.length; counter++){
        char now = chR[counter];
        if (now != ' ') {
            System.out.println(now);
        }else {
            System.out.println('.');
        }
    }



}
  }
```

And for this program it says:

```
Arrays_ToCjarArray(not working).java:6: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method toCharArray()
location: class java.lang.String[]
char chR[] = sentenceBest.toCharArray();        
                             ^
 1 error
```

Number #2 Program:

```
class Arrays_3 {
public static void main(String[] args){

    boolean numbers[] [] = new boolean[10] [10];

    numbers[9] [8] = true;

    System.out.println(numbers[9][8] + "!!!");


    String names[] = {"Marton", "Balint", "Thomas", "David", "John", "Peter", "Andy", "Daniel", "Josh", "James", "Erling", "Romeo", "Vincent", "Fabian"};

    System.out.println("The origional order: ");
    for (int counter = 0; counter < names.length; counter++){
        String newName = names[counter];
        System.out.println(counter + ": " + newName);
    }


    System.out.println("The Alphabetical order: ");

    Arrays

    for (int counter2 = 0; counter2 < names.length; counter2++) {
        System.out.println(counter2 + ": " + names);
    }


}
       }
```

And the same thing. Cannot find Symbol. Sooo annoying.

```
Arrays_3.java:21: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable Arrays
location: class Arrays_3
Arrays.sort(names);
    ^
1 error
```

I really don't understand this because this source code was from a great(so far) book called Sams teach you Java in 24 hours. So I really don't understand this. Any help would be apreciated well.

Answer (score 11):

1.[`toCharArray()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray%28%29) is for `String` not `String[]`

2.You need to import [`Arrays`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) by adding

```
import java.util.Arrays;
```

Answer (score 0):

For your first error, you're trying to invoke [`String.toCharArray`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray%28%29) on a `String[]`. That's not happening because there is not any `toCharArray` method defined on arrays.

For your second error, you need to import [`java.util.Arrays`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html).

> Sooo annoying.

Sorry, but you *have* to read the error messages.

> I really don't understand this because this source code was from a great(so far) book called Sams teach you Java in 24 hours.

First, they probably leave off the `import` statements for brevity in the book, but include them in the source code that you can obtain elsewhere (online, included DVD, etc.). Second, are you *sure* that you typed everything in correctly. Check again.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `toCharArray` on an array. Arrays do not support this. Instead you must call the method on the string with:

```
char chR[] = sentenceBest[0].toCharArray();
```

You also need to import `java.util.Arrays` and figure out what that `Arrays` on a line by itself is doing.

Comment: Alright, thanks for answering, and now it works! thanks for spending your time solving my problem!! thanks again!!!

Answer (score 0):

In program 1:

```
String sentenceBest[] = {"This is the first sentence!"};
char chR[] = sentenceBest.toCharArray();
```

`sentenceBest` is a `String` array, not a single `String`. You should call the `toCharArray` method from one of the `String`s contained in the array. For this case, it should work with:

```
char chR[] = sentenceBest[0].toCharArray();
```

In program 2:

Class `Arrays` comes from `java.util.Arrays` that looks you haven't imported. Just add the clause:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
```

Comment: Yeahhh!!! Thanks, it works perfectly by now, you are a great programmer!!! Thanks again!!!